# Javascript RegEx to match a part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I am struggling with the problem that I want a regex to only match a part of a string.

Example: "item/12/settings" should match the regex. But if there is a  `/` after "settings", followed by anything, it should not match. 
E.g. "item/12/settings/option" should not match.

I have tried something like: `/\w+\/\d+\/\w+/g` but this also matches "item/12/settings/option".

How can I tell the regex to only match a string like `/\w+\/\d+\/\w+/g` and nothing else? This seems to be trivial, but I am fairly new to using regex and I can't quite wrap my head around it yet.

Comment: Add the anchors `^` & `$`. `/^\w+\/\d+\/\w+$/`

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like adding `\/{0}` so that there would be no tailing slash and other silly stuff which did not work. Now it's obvious to me since i spend the day reading up on RegEx.